# How do I form a sentence that could imply that it's not known whether the condition with the if clause got fulfilled or not?

Tags: conditionals, sequence-of-tenses

> 1. He might have reached home by now, if nobody had stopped him.

From what I know I could say that this sentence pretty much implies that the person I am talking about didn't reach his destination (home) by the time this sentence was spoken since he was stopped by someone.

But how do I form a sentence that could imply that it's not known whether the condition with the if clause got fulfilled or not, like it's not certain whether he was stopped by someone or not and it's not certain either whether that person has reached home by now.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the sentence is **[past unreal conditional](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/past-unreal-conditionals/3181755.html#:%7E:text=To%20form%20the%20past%20unreal,followed%20by%20the%20past%20participle.&text=A%20conditional%20sentence%20can%20start,clause%2C%20or%20the%20result%20clause.)** which means that what is described didn't occur.

To convert to something that might have occurred you replace with the regular conditional tense:

> He might have reached home by now, if nobody *has* stopped him .

Alternatively

> He might have reached home by now, if nobody stopped him .

could work.